# Please help to identify an animated movie: a boy lost on a jungle planet (80-90-s)

Tags: story-identification, movie, space, animation

I remember watching an animated movie (part of, because it was incomplete) on a videotape in the 90's. It was a full-length movie, not likely a series. Please help to identify.

- The movie was French (with English subtitles)
- The protagonist is a little boy lost on a jungle planet. His parents have perished before.
- A rag-tag rescue team travels in a spaceship to save him. The team includes a captain, some rogue prince and an old balding man with a patch on his head (and some other people I do not remember)
- The boy communicates with the team using an odd, egg-shape 2-way transmitter.
- The old man knows the planet where the boy is stranded pretty well
- The team lands on some planet which is populated with faceless people. They try to subvert the team, but the Rogue Prince rebels and the power of the faceless people is disrupted, giving the team a chance to fly away.
- The boy makes friends with some elephantine local creature.

Then the tape ended. It did not include any title or opening credits either, as someone tried to jam in as many films on the tape as possible.

Comment: @Otis it is the same movie indeed, but we remembered different details

Comment: TimSparrow, no disparagement intended. Duplicates are closed based on answers, not questions, for story ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Les Maîtres du temps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps) - "Masters of Time", or maybe "Time Lords" :)

The twist is

> that the young boy and the old balding man are the same person, due to time manipulation done by the Masters of Time.

Comment: Yes, looks like that's it!